# Deviation lines in Poincaré - disk model

Tags: area, hyperbolic-geometry

The question has been asked before I guess; two geodesics are given in  Poincaré disk model say $K=-1$ cut by a transversal $(T_1T_2)$.

[image]

Please help  find common yellow area and perimeter enclosed between two geodesic lines assuming the *deviatric non- geodesic* (center, radius ) is defined.

I could not find how the latter are exactly defined in any model.

Comment: I do not know what "deviatric" means, but it seems that in your picture the boundary of the hyperbolic disk is the circle going through the point labeled 6 on the x-axis. In this case both area and perimeter of the yellow region will be infinite.

Comment: Yes, the $ H_1H_3 $ circle is the Poincaré disk. The line $H_1 T_2 H_2$ is a  skew or deviational  intersection, a parallel line if you will. I do not know if any particular word in  this context commonly used. Just as we have a geodesic curvature $ \kappa_g  \ne o $ [ e.g., parallel latitudes on a sphere ] by Liouville theorem etc , there ought to be something  correspondingly. defined here also. To me the yellow area appears non-zero.

Comment: I find it really hard to tell what is what in your diagram, and would appreciate a clearer diagram a lot. Important points are not marked as points, all lines are the same color, the manually added labels are far from unambiguous, the grid is displayed, superfluous points are not hidden, and circular arcs do not end at the boundary of whichever circle bounds the Poincaré disk. GeoGebra lets you do all of these things better: rename, recolor and relabel points or lines as desired, draw circular arcs, hide labels and axes.

Comment: Alright. Give me sometime.. Regards.

Comment: Here is an exercise in hyperbolic geometry: Take a Euclidean disk $D$  which intersects both hyperbolic plane and it's complement. Then the intersection of $D$ with hyperbolic plane has infinite hyperbolic area.